# Clustered Quartz scheduler configuration

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm working on an application that uses Quartz for scheduling Jobs. The Jobs to be scheduled are created programmatically by reading a properties file. My question is: if I have a cluster of several nodes which of these should create schedules programmatically? Only one of these? Or maybe all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have used quartz in a web app, where users, among other things, could create quartz jobs that performed certain tasks.

We have had no problems on that app provided that at least the job names are different for each job. You can also have different group names, and if i remember correctly the jobgroup+jobname combination forms a job key.

Anyway we had no problem with creating an running the jobs from different nodes, but quartz at the time(some 6 months ago, i do not believe this has changed but i am not sure) did not offer the possibility to stop jobs in the cluster, it only could stop jobs on the node the stop command was executed on.

If instead you just want to create a fixed number of jobs when the application starts you better delegate that job to one of the nodes, as the jobs name/group will be read from the same properties file for each node, and conflicts will arise.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating them on all of them? I think you would get some conflict because of duplicate names. 
So I think one of the members should create the schedules during startup.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have one system scheduling jobs for the cluster if they are predefined in properties like you say. If all of the systems did it you would needlessly recreate the jobs and maybe put them in a weird state if every server made or deleted the same jobs and triggers.

You could simply only deploy the properties for the jobs to one server and then only one server would try to create them.

You could make a separate app that has the purpose of scheduling the jobs and only run it once.

If these are web servers you could make a simple secured REST API that triggers the scheduling process. Then you could write an automated script to access the API and kick off the scheduling of jobs as part of a deployment or whenever else you desired. If you have multiple servers behind a load balancer it should go to only one server and schedule the jobs which quartz would save to the database backed jobstore. The other nodes in the cluster would receive them the next time they update from the database.